# Trim pattern in a text between \n\n\n\n

Tags: regex, r, nlp, data-cleaning

I am cleaning text in R. My text has the form

> but he could not avoid the subject FULLSTOP \n\n\n\n\nsimilar pieces
>   by the author\n\n\nlife is great 13022015\nreal men don t eath quiche
>   22042013\nback to the future 01072012\n\n\n\n and as he takes the
>   stage here wednesday night to rally democrats around hillary clinton
>   mr FULLSTOP  obama will revisit his own promise to guide the nation
>   into an era of reconciliation and unity harking back to the themes
>   that propelled his improbable rise but that seem even more out of
>   reach today FULLSTOP \n\n\n\n\nobama at convention to lay out stakes for
>   a divided nation \n\n\n\n  we get frustrated with political gridlock worry
>   about racial divisions are shocked and saddened by the madness of
>   orlando or nice mr FULLSTOP

I'm trying to get rid of

> \n\n\n\n\nsimilar pieces by the author\n\n\nlife is great 13022015\nreal men don t eath quiche 22042013\nback to the future 01072012\n\n\n\n

so to obtain something like

> but he could not avoid the subject FULLSTOP and as he takes the stage
>   here wednesday night to rally democrats around hillary clinton mr
>   FULLSTOP obama will revisit his own promise to guide the nation into
>   an era of reconciliation and unity harking back to the themes that
>   propelled his improbable rise but that seem even more out of reach
>   today FULLSTOP \n\n\n\n\nobama at convention to lay out stakes for a
>   divided nation \n\n\n\n we get frustrated with political gridlock
>   worry about racial divisions are shocked and saddened by the madness
>   of orlando or nice mr FULLSTOP

I'm trying with something like

`gsub("\\\n{3,}(similar pieces)?.*\\\n{3,}", "", my_string)`or `gsub("\\\n{3,}(similar pieces)?.*?\\\n{3,}", "", my_string)`

But it overtrims or does not work.

Any help (as well as an explanation of what I'm doing wrong and why the alternative works) would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is the string you provided exact C string literal? I mean, are there newlines inside or combinations of a ``\`` and `n`?

Comment: yes, this is just a string of text. just as if you entered it as

`my_string = 'but he could not avoid the subject FULLSTOP \n\n\n\n\nsimilar pieces by the author\n\n\nlife is great 13022015\nreal men don t eath quiche 22042013\nback'`

Comment: Try [`sub(" *\n{5}.*?\n{4} *", " ", s)`](https://ideone.com/lYMmf9).

Comment: This works great. Thanks!!

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match everything between the first 5 newline symbols up to the first 4 newline symbols.

I suggest a  `*\n{5}.*?\n{4} *` regex:

- `*` - zero or more literal spaces
- `\n{5}` - 5 newline symbols
- `.*?` - zero or more any characters up to the first....
- `\n{4}` - 4 LF symbols
- `*` - zero or more literal spaces (just to trim the match)

and replace with a space.

Use `sub` since you only need 1 replacement:

```
sub(" *\n{5}.*?\n{4} *", " ", s)
```

See [R demo](https://ideone.com/lYMmf9)